# how to insert value and use subquery to insert the last value?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables `customer` and `shipping_details`,

```
customer

first_name
last_name
phone
shipping_detail_id


shipping_details

shipping_detail_id
address
```

where the shipping id that I need to insert has an address of 'fakeadressstreet'

The values I want to insert are 'Jackson,' mike',12345,(shipping detail id where address is = fakeadressstreet).
the last value I need to insert depends on another column which is my second table no sure how to insert that value but  I hope it makes sense.

Comment: which rdbms you are using ? tag the correct. what have you tried to do that ?

Comment: it is tagged as mysql

Comment: first insert your address than you have the last_inserted_id which you cqan use

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
insert into customer ( first_name,
                       last_name,
                       phone,
                       shipping_detail_id
                     )

(SELECT   'Jackson' as first_name,
          'Mike' as last_name,
          12345 as phone,
          t1.shipping_detail_id
FROM shipping_details 
WHERE address = fakeadressstreet
) as t1 ;
```